# Trouble using underscore's findWhere method to update array value

Tags: typescript, underscore.js

I can't seem to figure this out, though I'm pretty positive i've used this approach before.

I have an array of objects that is initialized before the constructor method.

```
servers: ServerObject[] = [
    {
        name: 'dev',
        disabled: true
    },
    {
        name: 'qa',
        disabled: true
    },
    {
        name: 'prod',
        disabled: true
    }
];
```

The idea is to toggle server permissions after login. So based on what tokens are returned, set disabled to false. This occurs in the constructor method. Here is what that looks like:

```
_.each(this.tokens, (item:TokenObject) => {

    // print array -> target property is correctly set to 'true'
    console.log(this.servers);

    // print object before change -> target property is correctly set to 'true'
    console.log(_.findWhere(this.servers, {name: item.name}));

    _.findWhere(this.servers, {name: item.name}).disabled = false;

    // print object after change -> target property is correctly set to 'false'
    console.log(_.findWhere(this.servers, {name: item.name}));

    // print array -> target property is incorrectly set to 'true'
    console.log(this.servers);

})
```

I need `this.servers` to show this:

```
{
    name: 'qa',
    disabled: false
},
```

I also tried doing this underscore's findIndex method and the console messages are the same as above. Here is what this looked like:

```
this.servers[_.findIndex(this.servers, {name: item.name})].disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
this.tokens.forEach((item:TokenObject) => 
    this.servers.find(server=>server.name === item.name).disabled = false;
})
```

Comment: Same result. I assume the closing bracket after item.name was a mistake though right?

Comment: See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

I test this code:

```
const servers: any[] = [
  {name: 'dev', disabled: true},
  {name: 'qa', disabled: true},
  {name: 'prod', disabled: true}
];

[{name: 'prod'}].forEach((item) => servers.find(server => server.name === item.name).disabled = false);
console.log(servers);
console.log(servers.filter(server => !server.disabled));
```

**Results**:

- First Log:

> "[{"name":"dev","disabled":true},{"name":"qa","disabled":true},{"name":"prod","disabled":false}]"

- Second log:

> "[{"name":"prod","disabled":false}]"

this help you?